# Android Sound Resetting

Tags: java, android, audio, android-mediaplayer

My app plays a coin sound every time a button is pressed.

```
coin_sound.start();
```

You can easily press faster than the coin sound.  When this happens I want the coin sound to start from the beginning ever time  the button is pressed.

```
if(coin_sound.isPlaying()){
    coin_sound.reset();
    coin_sound = MediaPlayer.create(getContext(), R.raw.coin02);
}
coin_sound.start();
```

The problem with this is that loading a media file tiny as it may be is still a relatively slow process.  When you start to click the button really fast the app lags hard.

Are there any solutions to my problem?  The only idea I have is to do something with an array of coin_sounds, but this method seems like it will be messy and gross...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other answer posted here is somewhat correct. You should not call `create` over and over.

The code in that answer has a problem, though. The `reset` method sends the `MediaPlayer` into the idle state, where it is illegal to call most other methods. If you were to go that route, you have to call methods in the following order:

```
coin_sound.reset();
coin_sound.setDataSource(...);
coin_sound.prepare();
coin_sound.start();
```

The difference between calling `create` and the previous sequence of method calls is simply the creation of a new instance. That, however, is not the quickest way to do what should be done.

You should simply call `coin_sound.seekTo(0);` when you want the current playing sound to restart. So do something like:

```
if (coin_sound.isPlaying()) coin_sound.seekTo(0);
else coin_sound.start();
```

That assumes you have left the `MediaPlayer` in the prepared state so `start` can be called. You can accomplish that by calling `reset`, `setDataSource`, and `prepare` in the `onCompletion` listener. Also, make sure to call `release` when the sound is no longer needed.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are initiating coin_sound in the button click event, try this

initiate this variable in your oncreate method

```
coin_sound = MediaPlayer.create(getContext(), R.raw.coin02);
```

then make this your code for your button

```
if(coin_sound.isPlaying()){
coin_sound.reset();
}
coin_sound.start();
```

the problem is you are recreating a new media player each time the button is clicked so the new media player doesnt think there is a sound

and do you need to start it again with `coin_sound.start();`? doesnt restart stop then start the sound for you?

Comment: As per my knowledge RESET does not RESTART the sound it deletes it.